# How to get a list of objects in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, prolog-findall

I was resolving some prolog exercises when I fond myself with some difficulties resolving the following one:
Consider you have this fact base about object:

```
object(obj1). 
object(obj2). 
object(obj3). 
object(obj4). 
object(obj5). 
material(obj1,wood). 
material(obj2,wood). 
material(obj3, glass). 
material(obj4, glass). 
material(obj5, iron). 
type(obj1, able). 
type(obj2, chair). 
type(obj3, mesa). 
type(obj4, jar). 
type(obj5, rattle). 
weight(obj1, 10.5). 
weight(obj2, 1.5). 
weight(obj3, 1.6). 
weight(obj4, 0.5). 
weight(obj5, 1.8).
```

Now the idea is to make the predicate object_description(List) where List is the joining of each object with it's caracteristics, something like:

```
([obj1-wood-table-10.5, obj2-wood-chair-1.5, …, obj5-iron-rattle-1.8] )
```

I tried using bagof and findall but couldn't find the right answer.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
 ?- findall(O-M-T-W,(object(O),material(O,M),type(O,T),weight(O,W)),Res).
Res = [obj1-wood-able-10.5, obj2-wood-chair-1.5, obj3-glass-mesa-1.6, obj4-glass-jar-0.5, obj5-iron-rattle-1.8].
```

Answer (score 1):

```
classic style of prolog :

    member(_, []):-!,fail.
    member(X, [X| _]).
    member(X, [_|T]):- member(X,T).

    object_description(R):-
           get_all_objects([], R).

    get_all_objects(T, [H|R]):-
          get_object(H),
          not(member(H,T)),
          get_all_objects([H|T], R).
    get_all_objects([], []).

    get_object(Obj):-
          object(X),
          material(X,M),
          type(X, T),
          weight(X, W),
          concat(X, "-", R1),
          concat(R1, M, R2),
          concat(R2, "-", R3),
          concat(R3, T, R4),
          concat(R4, "-", R5),
          concat(R5, W, Obj).

% // concat(str1, str2, str3) if your compilator have'nt you must make it or use other %//analog, idea is  str1+str2=str3
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the input format. It's a little easier to search now.
I hope it's OK like this.

```
obj(obj1, material, wood).
obj(obj2, material, wood).
obj(obj3, material, glass).
obj(obj4, material, glass).
obj(obj5, material, iron).
obj(obj1, type, table).
obj(obj2, type, chair).
obj(obj3, type, mesa).
obj(obj4, type, jar).
obj(obj5, type, rattle).
obj(obj1, weight, 10.5).
obj(obj2, weight, 1.5).
obj(obj3, weight, 1.6).
obj(obj4, weight, 0.5).
obj(obj5, weight, 1.8).
```

Given this input format you can now map it to a list (of lists) e.g. like this:

```
object_description(List) :-
    findall(Id-TmpList, bagof(Type-Value, obj(Id, Type, Value), TmpList), List).
```

This doesn't produce the exact output format that you have in the question, but does give something similar (and maybe easier to process further).

Usage:

```
?- object_description(List).
List = [obj1-[material-wood, type-table, weight-10.5],
        obj2-[material-wood, type-chair, weight-1.5],
        obj3-[material-glass, type-mesa, weight-1.6],
        obj4-[material-glass, type-jar, weight-0.5],
        obj5-[material-iron, type-rattle, ... - ...]].
```